# C++, entering strings or chars in int arrays outputs 0 instead of ascii or error

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been testing this piece of code on visual studio c++.

Curiously the output if I enter any character first, the program stops and outputs 0, I was expecting the ASCII code or an error but I 0 instead. What is the reason for that?

```
int x[10];  int s;
    cin >> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        cin >> x[i]; 
    }
    cout << x[0];
```

Comment: The reason is because "X" is not a valid number.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: If you want the ASCII code, you should use `cin` with a char, not an int. Then it will be read as a character. The program won't give you any ASCII code unless you specifically ask for it, because otherwise, if the program gives you the number 65, you would be unable to tell if the user entered the number 65 or the letter 'A' (ASCII code 65).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the read was successful:

```
int x[10];  int s;
if (!(cin >> s)) {
    cout << "Read failed\n";
    return;
}

int i = 0;
for (; i < s && cin >> x[i]; i++){
}
cout << "successful reads: " << i << '\n';
if (i > 0) {
    cout << x[0];
}
```